# Checking for new IMAP mail with Java

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to implement a small tool using JavaMail to access my IMAP email in specific folders. Then notify if there are new emails in these folders. I'm not necessarily interested in just knowing about unread messages. Since messages may have been read (in a shared mailbox scenario) but may still be new to me.

I'm thinking of reading the folder and storing the UID of the newest message. Then comparing that UID the next time I check. However, I can't find any information in the Javamail documentation on how to find the newest message without going through the entire message list and sorting by date and/or message number.

Is there a better way to find out about new messages? Is there an easy way to tell JavaMail I only want the newest message in the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to an [`IMAPFolder`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html) and use `getMessagesByUID(long start, long end)` and `LASTUID`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail API has got some searching mechanism. You could search into a inbox folder like:

```
Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.RECENT), true));
```

It only provides unread messages in your inbox.